# Is the density of scale mixtures of Normal-Gamma log-concave?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, density-function

Consider the following density function (unnormalized)
$$p(y;b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2\left(b+\frac 5u\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{b+\frac 5u}} u^{1/2}\exp\left(-\dfrac{2u}{3}\right)du.$$

Is it true that $p(y;b)$ is a log-concave function in $b$ when $y$ is considered fixed?

My attempt: First of all, It is easy to plot $\log p(y;b)$ as a function of $b$ for a fixed value of $y$, and I've gotten a good hint that the curve is indeed concave. Note that one can think of $p(y;b)$ as a scale mixture of normal-gamma densities. I am aware that normal and gamma both are log-concave densities. However, I am not immediately able to see why that makes $p(y;b)$ log-concave as well. It is useful to know that the integral cannot be put into any standard closed form. One idea I had was to look at the integral as an expectation $p(y;b)=\mathbb{E}_u[\text{integrand}]$, where $u\sim \text{Gamma}(3/2,3/2)$, but this route requires the **joint** (log)concavity of the integrand in $(b,u)$ which seems like a formidable task to check through the means of the Hessian. Is there any other approach one can take to prove the proposed log-concavity?

PS: there was a trivial error in my previous argument (where I said those Hessians are negative definite, in fact, they aren't). The question remains open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the function $p(y;b)$ cannot be a log-concave for all fixed $y$. Let me show this for $y=0$. In this case,
$$p(0;b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{b+\frac 5u}} u^{1/2}\exp\left(-\dfrac{2u}{3}\right)du.$$

is **both convex and log-convex** over $b>0$.

Considering that the function $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+\frac 5u}}$$ is well-defined and convex over $b>0$ for any fixed value of $u>0$, $p(0;b)$ is also convex in $b$.

Moreover, after applying the transformation $x=\frac{5}{u}$, the integration used in the definition of $p(0;b)$ can be calculated explicitly, see this Wolfram link: [explicit formula of $p(0;b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2CSqrt%5Bb%2Bx%5D%5DPower%5Bx%2C-4.5%5DExp%5BDivide%5B-10%2C3x%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C%5Cinfty%7D%5D). The log of this function, which is plotted here: [plot of $\log p(0;b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20-7%20log%28b%29%20%2B%20log%28%28-0.970813%20b%5E3.5%20%2B%200.436866%20b%5E4.5%20-%200.19659%20b%5E5.5%20%2B%200.0491474%20b%5E6.5%29%20e%5E%2810%2F%283%20b%29%29%20%2B%200.914286%20b%5E3%201F1%284%2C%204.5%2C%2010%2F%283%20b%29%29%29%20%20from%20-2%20to%2010), is clearly a convex function over $b>0$.

---

**Responding to a comment below** on the unimodality of the following function:

$$f(b)=\mathbb E_{N} \left [ -\log \mathbb E_{G} \left[\dfrac{\exp\left(-\frac{N^2}{2\left(b+\frac 5G\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{b+\frac 5G}}  \right ]\right ] $$

with $N \sim \text{Nromal}(0,1)$ and $G \sim \text{Gamma}(3/2,3/2)$, My numerical checks show that the function:

$$ g(b,y,u)= \dfrac{\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2\left(b+\frac 5u\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{b+\frac 5u}} $$

for fixed values of $y \in \mathbb R $ and $u>0$ is **quasi-concave**, which can be [increasing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=plot%20Exp%5BDivide%5B-10%2Cb%2BDivide%5B5%2C100%5D%5D%5DDivide%5B1%2CSqrt%5Bb%2BDivide%5B5%2C100%5D%5D%5D%20from%20b%3D0%20to%2010), [decreasing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=plot%20Exp%5BDivide%5B-1%2Cb%2BDivide%5B5%2C1%5D%5D%5DDivide%5B1%2CSqrt%5Bb%2BDivide%5B5%2C1%5D%5D%5D%20from%20b%3D0%20to%2010), or [unimodal](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=plot%20Exp%5BDivide%5B-1%2Cb%2BDivide%5B5%2C100%5D%5D%5DDivide%5B1%2CSqrt%5Bb%2BDivide%5B5%2C100%5D%5D%5D%20from%20b%3D0%20to%2010) with a single maximum for different values of $y$ and $u$. However, unfortunately, the summation of quasi-concave functions is not necessarily a quasi-concave function, and thus we cannot use this property. The above observations indicate that analytically proving that $f(b)$ is unimodal seems very difficult. **Hence, the best way to realize whether $f(b)$ is unimodal or not is to numerically check it.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That explains! I did experiment with some values of $y$ but they were all positive. Do you think the function  $f(b)=\mathbb{E}[-\log p(y;b)]$ has a unique minimum? (where $y$ is distributed as $N(0,1)$ let's say). Answering that question was my initial goal, which is why I tried to prove the density $p(y;b)$ is log-concave, but as it turns out, that isn't the case.

Comment: @Maximal_inequality have you plotted the expectation?

Comment: @Maximal_inequality I added more details after doing some numerical checks. It seems that the best way to check the unimodality of $f(b)$ is to check it numerically.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I only plotted the functions for a few positive values of $y$ and mostly observed convexity of $f(b)$. This doubt came up in my own research on bayesian misspecified models.